# i have not receive the transaction

Tags: transactions

i have transation asf :
BITCOIN-PAYMENT HAS BEEN SUCCESSFULLY SENT:

Transaction Detail:     $750,500
Recipient Address :   bxd94D0A4aE4F29bf408c48d8217fB53cb68a22Db3
Date:                           March 8, 2024 1:42 PM
Amount:                     12.00 BTC
Status:                        Completed

and i checked it but none

Answer (score 2):

You can use any "blockchain explorer" to see that  [bxd9...2Db3 is not a valid Bitcoin address](https://blockchair.com/search?q=bxd94D0A4aE4F29bf408c48d8217fB53cb68a22Db3)

Bitcoin addresses usually start with 1, 3 or bc1 so it hard to see how you could have generated that as a receiving address using a Bitcoin wallet.

Anyone claiming they sent Bitcoin to that address is either mistaken, incompetent or lying.